# Who is faster? AppFabric Cache or Memcached?

Tags: azure, memcached, appfabric

We use the MS AppFabric Cache to store the central session. But we want to know how fast this store? Realties who used to do the virtual machine and Memcached on this machine?

thanks a lot!

Comment: do you store only authentication data or more data ? memcached is faster when you store bigger kay/value pairs into id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have seen any benchmarks on this so its a hard one to answer but the new Windows Azure Caching service released on June 7th addresses a lot of the performance issues of the Distributed Multi-Tenanted Azure Caching Service.

Below are extracts from Haishi's blog on Azure Caching, note Windows Azure Caching now supports Memcached interoperability too...

> "The cluster utilizes free memory spaces on your Cloud Service host machines, and the cluster service process can either share the host machines of your web/worker roles, or run on dedicated virtual machines when you use dedicated caching worker roles"

http://haishibai.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/windows-azure-caching-service-memcached.html

> Fast performance. The cluster either collocates with your roles, or runs in close proximity based on affinity groups. This helps to reduce latency to minimum. In addition, you can also enable local cache on your web/worker roles so that they get fastest in-memory accesses to cached items as well as notification support.